# Exporting Talend Job into Visual Studio 2010 causing java.io.IOException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, talend

I am using Talend Open StudioV5.4 for Data Integration. I am providing a brief description of the jobs I created in Talend. I have created a job name Refresh_bFO_Table which connects to Salesforce.com and Fetch Data from Account and Opportunity Table and with those data its populate a local database named OFOTaccdb. In this Local database there are two tables bFO_Account and bFO_Opportunity which get populated with these data retrieved from SalesForce.

Now, for connecting to salesforce we have used OAuth2.0 for authentication. We have provided the consumerSecret, consumerkey, redirect URI in Talend tSalesforceComponent configuaration and jobs are running perfectly from Talend.

We have created a UI Interface using VB2010.so,after successful completion of Talend job we are exporting this job into Visual Studio's bin folder as executable code, now, when we are running the project from Visual Studio it gets an authentication error regarding OAuth2.0

```
  Exception in component tSalesforceConnection_1
  java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:  https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.talend.salesforce.oauth.OAuthClient.refreshToken(OAuthClient.java:104)
    at ofotenhancement.refresh_bfo_table_0_1.Refresh_bFO_Table.tSalesforceConnection_1Process(Refresh_bFO_Table.java:533)
    at ofotenhancement.refresh_bfo_table_0_1.Refresh_bFO_Table.runJobInTOS(Refresh_bFO_Table.java:2318)
    at ofotenhancement.refresh_bfo_table_0_1.Refresh_bFO_Table.main(Refresh_bFO_Table.java:2169)
```

I have inspected the source code of tSalesforceComponent from Talend with line no which VS2010 is mentioning in this exception.Source code is as follows:

```
 token_tSalesforceConnection_1 = oauthClient_tSalesforceConnection.refreshToken(storedRefreshToken_tSalesforceConnection_1);
```

Well my refresh token is in a property file named token.properties:

```
#Wed Jun 18 10:34:11 IST 2014
refreshtoken=5Aep861vKMLoVl4zz9FUGsd2kHAPryhoIRCvNajnyB2TR4OVopNSy
N1zDjeFZfa6Ehq0A1IPVRX_JcWtgvV6pgk
```

Jobs are running properly from Talend; the problem is occurring from VS2010.

Comment: your connection token to salesforce - are being read from .properties file or context groups in talend job?- as could it be that these context/token values are not having correct values during export of jobs from talend studio - you have an option of selecting context group during export - may be you can try to print contexts variables in jobs - so that you can be sure that your contexts or token are being passed correctly..

Comment: Thanks for the hints.I have exported the context now.but there is a problem regarding token.properties file.In Talend for OAuth2.0 there is a option called token.properties for storing refresh token.It gets stored in a physical location of my machine.now when I am exporting job and making an .exe from VS2010,how to deal with this physical location of properties file.when different user will install the .exe file in their machine then how this properties file will get resolved????